# Generate random string-java and xml

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, random

I am trying to write a code to generate a random string from a set of arrays.  I need help with fixing this code and then what do I include in the xml file to ensure that the code from java will work?  Please help!  Thanks!

Below is my code from java:

```
package com.momsmealplanner;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class OutcomeActivity extends Activity 
{
    public String[] myString;

    Resources res = getResources();
    myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.restArray);

    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    int[] textViews = 
    {
            //add textviews to this array
    };

    for (int v : textViews)
    {
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(v);

        tv.setText(myString[random.nextInt(myString.length)]);
    }
}
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I know!  I posted both of them!  Can you offer advice instead of saying it is a duplicate? Jeez

Comment: *"Jeez"*. It's called moderation, that's why there is a *mark as duplicate* option. Looking over the fact that you keep posting the same question just to get more views, what exactly is the problem? If it crashes post a stack trace.